# vue and globla axios request

Tags: vue.js, axios

Currently I have the following axios post request as an example:

in boot/axios.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import qs from 'qs'

Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
Vue.prototype.$qs = qs
Vue.prototype.$serverUrl = 'http://localhost:8090/api/';
```

In my page:

```
this.$axios.post(this.$serverUrl, null, 
{ data: {version: "1", command: "login", email: this.regEmail, password: this.password, API: 2, token: "dummy"}, 
transformRequest: [(data, headers) => {return this.$qs.stringify(data);}]})
.then((response) => {...})
.catch((err) => {...})
.finally(() => {...})
```

This is working ok but I want to globalize it so the base url and other fixed parameters will already be there and I will just send the additional parameters for a specific call:

```
this.$postCall(call specific params...)
.then((res) => {...})
.catch((err) => {...})
.finally(() => {...})
```

I understand that I should prototype something like

```
Vue.prototype.$postCall = function(param) {
}
```

But i'm not sure how the callbacks should go back to the caller...

**Edit:**
I did the following:

```
Vue.prototype.$postCall = function (params) {
    return this.$axios.post('http://localhost:8090/api', null, { data: { API: 2, version: "1", params}});
}
```

and called it:

```
this.$postCall({ command: "login", email: this.regEmail, password: this.password, token: "dummy" })
```

In the debug I see the correct info key: value in params and I expected the additional params to be added to the fixed ones but they are not, what am I missing?

**Edit2:**
Fixed it by a simple loop

```
let theData = {
    API: 2, 
    version: "1", 
};
for (var k in params) {
    theData[k] = params[k];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other method you could create a custom instance for axios so it will use the default values when call `.get()` `.post()` etc.
https://github.com/axios/axios#custom-instance-defaults

e.g.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import qs from 'qs';

Vue.prototype.$axios = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8090/api/',
  transformRequest: [(data, headers) => qs.stringify(data)],
});
```

**Edit:**

1. how can I use it without the url parameter it expects?

For only post call to the url, you could do this by `this.$axios.post('/', /* ... */)`

2. the data parameters still need to be passed as before. I was wondering if there's a way to make a globalize post request function.

Make the `$postCall` returning the `axios.post()` promise
e.g.

```
Vue.prototype.$postCall = function (params) {
  return this.$axios.post('/', { version: "1", command: params.command /*, other params */ });
}
```

And you could use on the page

```
this.$postCall({ command: "some commmand" })
  .then((response) => {...})
  .catch((err) => {...})
  .finally(() => {...});
```

Comment: Nice trick but: 1. how can I use it without the url parameter it expects? this.$axios.post(URL?...),  2. the data parameters still need to be passed as before. I was wondering if there's a way to make a globalize post request function.

Comment: It looks like I'm almost there, can you please see my original post after the edit part?

Comment: @Amos If you could use ES5 or latest syntax, try use "Spread syntax" for merging objects which more simple, for example, `{ data: { API: 2, version: "1", ...params } }` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax